# Trouble with For loops sumArray

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am having trouble with `for` loops and I cannot seem to figure this out. I need to add the numbers in an array. The closest I get is I get the loop to print the array 1,2,3 three times with this code

```
function sumArray(num) {
  for (var i = 0; i < sumArray.length; i++) {
    var total = 0;
    console.log(num);
  }
}

sumArray([1,2,3])
```

and when I use this code all it does is log 1

```
function sumArray(num) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < sumArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(total += num[i]);
  }
}

sumArray([1,2,3])
```

At one point I got it to return undefined three times

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're looping over the wrong structure with this line:

```
for (var i = 0; i < sumArray.length; i++)
```

You want to loop over the `num` parameter you passed in. `sumArray` is the name of the *function*, and `sumArray.length` is the number of parameters of the function. Do this instead:

```
function sumArray(num) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    console.log(total += num[i]);
  }
}
```

You probably want to add a `return total;` in there as well so that `sumArray` returns the sum instead of just printing the running total as it loops.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome at Stack Overflow :) First of all, your naming things is kind of misleading, since `sumArray` argument is called `num` (which suggest that it accepts just a number, not an array) - I would suggest you to name it e.g. `arr`.

Secondly - remember about returning your `total` variable when the for loop finishes.

Lastly - `sumArray` is a function, then `sumArray.length` will return `1` - which is the amount of how many arguments function expects - so actually your loop will fire only once.

```js
function sumArray(arr) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    total += arr[i];
  }
  
  return total;
}

console.log(sumArray([1, 2, 3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.reduce()`:

```js
function sumArray(arr) {
   return arr.reduce((acc,curr) => acc + curr);
}

console.log(sumArray([1,2,3,4]));
```